# Can delete requests be tested from browser?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, postman

I'm currently learning about REST APIs and Spring Boot. I heard in a YouTube tutorial that DELETE requests can't be tested from a browser and can only be tested from applications like Postman. But on testing my code from Firefox, it worked fine. Can someone elaborate on this? Code looks like this.

```
@DeleteMapping("/employees")
    public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return "Deleting the employee details for the id " + id;
    }
```

Comment: Code is not a browser. The tutorial probably means a simple URL entered in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

> DELETE requests can't be tested from a browser

It means that if you directly paste the URL in browser's address bar, it defaults to GET method. So DELETE or POST or PUT can't be tested by just invoking a URL from browser.

But you can still use browser plugins or tools like Postman or Insomnia to choose the HTTP Method you want to invoke.

Comment: Pasting /employees?id=34 in my browser produces the correct result even though there is a DeleteMapping. It is not defaulting to GET

Comment: There is something strange for sure, you should be getting error with Http status code 405 (method not allowed). Can you check through browser's developer tool and share screenshot of API call